# How to resize some objects in a group in fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a group of two objects, what I want is that when resizing the group one of the objects does not change size but the position does.

I have searched the documentation but I can not find references to solve this problem.

```
var r = 15;
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    fill: 'blue',
    width: 100,
    height: 100

});
var linkBtn = new fabric.Circle({
    left: 50 + rect.width / 2 - r,
    top: 50 - r,
    strokeWidth: 1,
    radius: r,
    fill: '#fff',
    stroke: '#666'
});
var g = new fabric.Group([rect, linkBtn]);
g.hasRotatingPoint = false;
canvas.add(g);
```

when I stretch the width of the group, the object "linkBtn" is deformed like an oval, it happens the same with the height. I want that when changing the size, the object "linkBtn" is always the same size, and that is always half the width of the object "rect".

Answer (score 0):

Add {lockUniScaling : true} as the second parameter on this line

```
var g = new fabric.Group([rect, linkBtn], {lockUniScaling : true});
```

lockUniScaling
Prevents scaling in either X or Y direction but not in both. In other words, prevents non-proportional scaling of an object.